# Progress bar in Power shell script possible?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Im curious about having a progress bar for a function i've made, however i've been trying for the past hour of implementing it into my code but no luck....

Is it even possible , What my program does it reads a list of svr names and then basically invokes a function to grab information from a svr and write to file so i have raw data logs, however i get tired of looking at a blank screen so i wanted to add some sort of indicator .. :( but no luck ..

Would really appreciate some comments thank you all :)

Clear-Host

```
$serverList = Get-Content C:\RServerList.txt

$creds = Get-Credential

function Build_Directories
{
   foreach ($s in $serverList)
   {
     New-Item -ItemType directory -Path C:\Data\$s
    }
 }


function xecute_eLogs
{
    $i = 1
    foreach ($s in $serverList)
    {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -ScriptBlock {Get-EventLog -LogName security -EntryType "Error","Warning"} -credential $creds | Out-File "C:\Data\$s\sysElogs.txt"
        Write-Progress -Activity "Retrieving data from $s which is $i out of $($serverList.Count)" ` -percentComplete  ($i++*100/$serverList.Count)

    }
 }



Build_Directories
xecute_eLogs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Write-Progress`

here is an example:

```
$max = 25
for ($i = 1; $i -le $max; $i++)
{
     Write-Progress -Activity "Counting $i until $max" `
        -percentComplete  ($i*100/$max)
     sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

**EDIT**
Taking into consideration comment about status.

Adapted to your script it would look like this:

```
$i = 1
foreach ($s in $serverList)
{
     Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -ScriptBlock {Get-EventLog -LogName system -EntryType "Error","Warning"} -credential $creds | Out-File "C:\Data\$s\sysElogs.txt"

     Write-Progress -Activity "Retrieving data from $s which is $i out of $($serverList.Count)" -percentComplete  ($i++*100/$serverList.Count) -status Running
}
```

Comment: Wow if this works it would be cool, im going to try it out and take a look , the example you post $max , i tried to do an implementation like that but no luck :(...

Comment: Write-Progress requires Powershell V3 I believe

Comment: yup i have version 4.0 , i tried the cmd you posted and well it give me a RuntimeException saying Attempted to divide by 0 , is that because i have only one server in my txt file ?

Comment: i tried to the cmd with 2 servers in the txt file it work i see the bar but it prompts me with the following : 

cmdlet write-Progress at command pipeline position 1 
Supply values for the following parameters : Status: "Flashing prompt waiting for me to enter something"

Comment: can you update your question with the code you have tried? so we are looking at the same thing

Comment: yup one second will update since im working on two different computers lol long story

Comment: I just tried with a single string and not an array, during the foreach, Powershell will act as if the string is an array and update $s properly, $serverList.count will be equal to 1. However, I'm, running Powershell V5 so I don't know if that is new or was the same in V4.

Comment: Interesting because here I don't need to give it a status. I've updated the answer, lets give it a status while it's running. Added `-status Running` at the end of the write-progress command.

Comment: Never mind thank you all for your help. I had to make a permissions modification to retrieve logs remotely.